# Can Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 6 produce timelapse video without plugins?

Tags: timelapse, lightroom-6

I know that one can buy the plugin LRTimelapse for use with Lightroom 6 in the production of timelapse videos; my question is, is it required to make timelapse videos with Lightroom 6?

Comment: You can produce a proper timelapse with photoshop if you have it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can manually set the slide duration a slideshow to be 0.04s (25 fps). However, I've found that the resulting product isn't as good as other methods of stitching together timelapses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, LR can produce timelapse without preset. But it'll select the default fps which is more than 30fps. Your timelapse will look like a slide show, not like a video you are expecting. I think LRtimelapse.zip file is available online for free. It has 23, 24, 30 fps presets.